# Android/JAVA: Inner AsyncTask in a seperate file

Tags: java, android

This is the given situation:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity Implements Foo, Bar {

... not so much code ...

    private class GetSomeStuff extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
    ... lot of code ...
    }

    private class GetOtherStuff extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
    ... more code ...
    }

}
```

This situation makes my MainActivity very unreadable. This is a single activity app with many fragments, so the main activity only does the navigation and fragment management stuff. Is it possible to define these AsyncTask classes in another file so my code is more readable, keeping the accessibility?

thanks!

Comment: yes, create a separate class for the async task. 
and init in MainActivity.

Comment: Just a tip, Async tasks were deprecated in API level 30. If you're starting a new project, consider using other alternative like RXJava or Coroutines if you're considering Kotlin.

Comment: @KishanMaurya There is a reason why they are inner classes. Inner classes hold a reference to the containing class, so it can access private and protected members. These tasks will only be called from the containing class and I have to ensure that.

Comment: @AbedElazizShehadeh Sadly this is an old project targeting a specific device using API23

Comment: Pass the instance of your class as a parameter to the AsyncTask and hold onto the instance with a WeakReference. With this pattern you'll have to expose private vars from the class that you need access to from the Task, though.

Comment: @Egg Yes, but I want to avoid exposing private parts of my activity